# Split string by specified length array of each chunk

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I split a string to X chunks with length T,  if given an array of sizes.
When X is `len(array_chunks)` and T is `'array_chunks[i]`

```
array_chunks = [1,2,3]
my_string = "987654"
>> ['9', '87', "654"]
```

Comment: Iterate over `array_chunks` and construct slices from its items then use the slices to extract the characters from the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_chunks = [1,2,3]
my_string = "987654"
result = []
ind = 0
for i in array_chunks:
    result.append(my_string[ind: ind+i])
    ind+=i
```

As per below a list comprehension is also possible. I used a solution with `itertools.accumulate`

```
from itertools import accumulate
[my_string[i: i+j] for i, j in zip(accumulate(range(len(array_chunks))), array_chunks)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
array_chunks = [1,2,3]
my_string = "987654"
new_string = [my_string[sum(array_chunks[:i]):a+sum(array_chunks[:i])] if i != 0 else my_string[:a] for i, a in enumerate(array_chunks)]
```

Output:

```
['9', '87', '654']
```